Delphi 12.1 complete class at cursor
I have installed Delphi 12.1 and doesn't functione the complete class at cursor; also it doesn't function the "block completition" (I don't know the exact name) but it's the feature that if you digit "trye" and the space key automatically you have the block try except end.
I check the options but it seem all ok. I have checked

It is not the space key alone. It is Ctrl + space (and its name is "code completion"

The block completion sounds like code templates which are triggered with a TAB. So trye+TAB to get a try/except/end block.

This is two separate questions (one about Code Completion, and one about Code Templates). They should be in separate posts.
